# VirtualBox bridged Vms not getting response from DHCP server

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, dhcp

I have a few  Linux and windows VMs on my laptop that i run to test and do homework with.

I cannot get a response from DHCP servers in bridged mode with these vms. Nat works but Bridged does not at school or the library. When i run dhclient -v i get a timeout on the DHCPDISCOVER.

At home my dhcp server responds to requests from these vms.

My question is, can it be that their DHCP servers are configured not to respond to requests from VMs, and if so how that would be done seeing that the interface has its own Mac address to identify itself.

Just looking for some insight, not a big deal just wondering.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes that is one possibility.  They could be blocking traffic from certain MAC addresses.  You could possibly test this by changing the MAC address of your guest VM's.  Find out your laptop's MAC address, increment it by 1, and then assign that to one of the guests.  The first 6 digits of a MAC address are specific to a NIC manufacturer, so they could be filtering by that.

Answer (score -3):

Finally, after spending an entire day it turns out the problem lied with the fact I was connected to a 5Ghz network vs. 2.4Ghz. After switching, I was able to obtain an IP address in my VM.